# Why is RewriteBase not needed in Fedora?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04, fedora-21

I use Ubuntu and Fedora for personal and work. Ubuntu more so because they come pre-installed on work provided devices. Whenever I have to setup a web application on my `public_html`, I have to add a `RewriteBase` directive in `.htaccess` in order to get things working.

However, I recently noticed that I didn't set a RewriteBase in my Fedora Core (FC21) device and yet CakePHP run just fine. Urls were resolving correctly for user directories.

I've looked around in both machines comparing Apache settings. So far, I haven't located anything that seems to do the magic.

What have I been missing setting up on Ubuntu to achieve the same behavior? Or is this a Fedora Core specific change?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure public_html is actually defined as the document root on both servers. rewritebase is per directory, typically not needed if you are in the root directory. Something is up with your setup with Ubuntu I would presume.  Apache works the same across the board and also depending on version as well.

Comment: @PanamaJack Sorry, I'm not sure what you meant with the document root as these are user directories. Related to the topic however, the only difference I've seen on the two `userdir.conf` is that the `<Directory>` directive is outside the `<IfModule mod_userdir.c>` block on FC's, while it's inside on Ubuntu's. But, I think that shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks for your comment, pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The document for [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) mentions that it can be omitted provided that a context is provided by `Alias` or `userdir` for Apache >= **2.4.13**. Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Apache is at **2.4.7**, so figured it won't work yet there.